# git push failed with large repository (MOVE *some commit* failed,aborting (7/0))

Tags: git

We are using `https` protocol for git (to get synchronized with our wiki username/password), and try to `push` the local git repository to a bared remote repository with `sslVerify = false`. It works perfect with small repository but failed with our 3 Gigabytes repository. With the following error:

```
Fetching remote heads...
 refs/
 refs/tags/
 refs/heads/
updating 'refs/heads/tflux-middle-end-partition'
 from 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 to   2062f4b5b77bd698dd3f7b6dd43a51e37ca10a27
   sending 1026854 objects
MOVE da8e0adc291bb4690c57d0572f8006dbcf59ca17 failed, aborting (7/0)
Updating remote server info
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

At first glance, we thought it could be some time out error due to the https protocol, so we change the time out time to 4hours `DavMinTimeout 14400`, but it still didn't work.

Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

The message comes from [http-push.c](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/703f05ad5835cff92b12c29aecf8d724c8c847e2/http-push.c#L582), and is printed when curls does report a successful transmission. So either there is some error on the webserver (protocol permissions, file permissions), or you found a bug in curl. Maybe you can find traces about what is going wrong in your web server log. Also you can `git push -v <args>` to see more details of the transmission.